# OAuth 2 и Вконтакте

Tags: веб-программирование, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, oauth

Здравствуйте. Вот начинаю осваивать веб, а именно авторизацию через соцсети, так что не судите строго.
Хочу разобраться, как работает данный протокол.  
Сначала опишу, как я понимаю принцип работы.
Мы регистрируем приложение вконтакте для получения доступа к использованию их АПИ. Получаем секретный код, который будем использовать при запросе. Затем мы делаем чудо кнопку "Войти через Вконтакте". При этом вешаем на нее запрос к АПИ, в котором указываем редирект, права и так далее. Пользователь нажимает и попадает на окно для подтверждения использования его данных. Получаем так называемый token на разрешение или же отказ. После подтверждения мы попадаем на ссылку, указанную в редиректе, то есть на наш сайт.  
Получаем в JSON или XML формате данные пользователя. И тут начинаются вопросы.   
 1. При получении данных пользователя мы создаем новую запись в таблице пользователей. Пароль должен генерироваться автоматически?
 2. Как проходит процесс при повторной авторизации через вконтакте? Мы посылаем запрос к апи, если опять получаем токен, то смотрим в базе, нету ли такого пользователя по ид, если есть, то автоматически выполняем вход, если нет, то регистрируем и тоже входим. Или другой принцип работы?
 3. Следует ли постоянно хранить токен, полученный при регистрации?

Объясните, пожалуйста, общий принцип работы при повторной регистрации, и если я неправильно понял, то и для перовой. 
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации ВК см. [Авторизация сайтов](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites) — там очень подробно расписан весь процесс.

У вас в вопросе после подтверждения пользователем в окне прав доступа идёт не совсем  правильное описание. Пользователь попадает на сайт с параметром code, ваш сервер "меняет" его напрямую с ВК на access_token, который живёт обычно 12 часов. Т.е. потом надо снова заставлять юзера жать на кнопку авторизации у вас на сайте.

1. Паролей здесь вообще нет. От ВК напрямую придёт user_id авторизованного пользователя. Можно его использовать как id пользователя в БД. Вы можете проставить тому собственную куки, по которой сможете его "узнавать" в течение какого-то времени.
2. Всё так, как вы написали.
3. Токен живёт 12 часов. Сколько держится у вас сессия? Скорее всего, хранить токен в БД нет смысла.

Comment: На счет пароля я имел ввиду то, что на некоторых сайтах автоматически генерируется пароль, но его можно изменить в профиле при авторизации. 
И можно таким образом входить не через ВК, а напрямую используя пароль и логин (логин = ид вк) или же через вк без ввода пароля.

Comment: Это можно, но к схеме OAuth и ВКонтакте уже отношения не имеет. У вас есть авторизованный через ВК пользователь и его id.

Дальше с этим добром можете делать что угодно: сгенерировать ему пароль, позволить привязать аккаунты google, facebook и twitter, чтобы он мог входить и через них, при этом оказываться всё в том же едином аккаунте вашей системы.